# Need help for a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table structure:

```
id  id_parent   id_origin   level   name
1   0   1   1   PHP
2   0   2   1   Javascript
3   0   3   1   SMARTY
4   0   4   1   HTML
5   1   1   2   Basic
6   1   1   2   Date & Math Function
8   2   2   2   DOM
9   5   1   3   Introduction
10  5   1   3   Session & Cookies
12  2   2   2   Introduction
13  4   4   2   Basic Structure
14  6   1   3   PHP Date Function
16  3   3   2   Basic Syntax
26  4   4   2   Table
```

I want result like below format

```
Myfinalstr
-----------
PHP
PHP->Basic
PHP->Basic->Introduction
PHP->Basic->Session & Cookies
PHP->Date & Match Function
PHP->Date & Match Function->PHP Date Function
Javascript
Javascript->DOM
Javascript->Introduction
SMARTY
SMARTY->Basic Syntax
HTML
HTML->Basic Structure
HTML->Table
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: It looks like a question about [hierarchical sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347067/hierarchical-data-in-mysql) to me.

Comment: @Craig White :  I want to write a query for above table structure to get the result as a coloumn myfinalstr.I have tried with self join and use concat_ws("->",a.name,b,name,c.name) in the select query.Ex-: " SELECT concat_ws("->",a.name,b.name) FROM `tts__category` a,`tts__category` b WHERE b.id_parent=a.id "Its upto level

Comment: How deep can the hierarchy be? If you want to do this in a simple SELECT query, you join the table to itself as many times as the maximum depth of the hierarchy to flatten it.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: The hierarchy will upto 4 level.I know it will be done by self join with itself 4 times But I could not able to write the query.

Comment: @Priyabrata: SQL statements (both for table creation and data insertion) are much more useful than tab separated data when it comes to displaying table contents. [Code](http://sscce.org/) is [king](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: ... As for hierarchical data, read ["What are the Options for Storing Hierarchical Data in a Relational Database?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: @outis: I have done the above rquirement in different way.Let me explain about my idea.I have added an extra colomn "tree",at the time of insertions of item ,I am creating 'what will be the tree' and then inserting in the 'tree' colomn.But Here I am looking for a query which can retreive data in the above format.Is it possible,If yes, Please help me or suggest the new table structure.

Comment: @Priyabrata: You haven't done something different. The linked question has links to further pages that address your current schema (adjacency list+depth), the difficulties it causes for certain queries (such as the one you desire), and how to surpass those difficulties. In short, it answers your questions.

Comment: @outis: Thank you I got your point,But will you help me to write query for current table strucutre?

Comment: @Priyabrata: there's good [lazy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris) (getting computers to do your work) and bad lazy (getting people to do your work). Right now, you're exhibiting the latter. Read the links, then ask specific questions if you're having problems implementing what's outlined in the material. The short of it is it's not possible with the current schema in MySQL. The documents describe various options for changing the schema.

Comment: @outis: Thank you agai,for such guidance.Really from Now I will work hard.

Answer (score 4):

The following isnt a complete solution but it will get you started:

**Example stored procedure call**

```
mysql> call chapter_hier(1);
+----+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+
| id | category_name        | id_parent | parent_category_name | depth |
+----+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+
|  1 | PHP                  |      NULL | NULL                 |     0 |
|  5 | Basic                |         1 | PHP                  |     1 |
|  6 | Date & Math Function |         1 | PHP                  |     1 |
|  9 | Introduction         |         5 | Basic                |     2 |
| 10 | Session & Cookies    |         5 | Basic                |     2 |
| 14 | PHP Date Function    |         6 | Date & Math Function |     2 |
+----+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

$result = $conn->query(sprintf("call chapter_hier(%d)", 1));
```

**Full script and test data**

```
drop table if exists chapters;
create table chapters
(
id smallint unsigned not null primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
id_parent smallint unsigned null,
key (id_parent)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into chapters (id, name, id_parent) values
(1,'PHP',null),
(2,'Javascript',null),
(3,'SMARTY',null),
(4,'HTML',null),
(5,'Basic',1),
(6,'Date & Math Function',1),
(8,'DOM',2),
(9,'Introduction',5),
(10,'Session & Cookies',5),
(12,'Introduction',2),
(13,'Basic Structure',4),
(14,'PHP Date Function',6),
(16,'Basic Syntax',3),
(26,'Table',4);


drop procedure if exists chapter_hier;
delimiter #

create procedure chapter_hier
(
in p_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

create temporary table hier(
 id_parent smallint unsigned, 
 id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned default 0
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select id_parent, id, v_depth from chapters where id = p_id;
create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from chapters c
        inner join tmp on c.id_parent = tmp.id and tmp.depth = v_depth) then

        insert into hier select c.id_parent, c.id, v_depth + 1 from chapters c
            inner join tmp on c.id_parent = tmp.id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

        set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
 c.id,
 c.name as category_name,
 p.id as id_parent,
 p.name as parent_category_name,
 hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join chapters c on hier.id = c.id
left outer join chapters p on hier.id_parent = p.id
order by
 hier.depth;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end #

delimiter ;
```

Hope it helps :)